# Updating UI inside a thread (Android Studio/JAVA)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I am creating a small game over wifi-direct through sockets on Android. On the client receiving thread I am listening for Messages from the other device:

```
class ReceivingThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            BufferedReader input;
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    final String messageStr = input.readLine();
                    if (messageStr != null) {

                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, messageStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                activity.handleMessage(messageStr);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                input.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

And the toast shows the message just fine, but the app crashes on `activity.handleMessage()`. This is what the method does (cut it down just to one case, just for the point of the method):

```
public void handleMessage(String msg){
    switch(msg){
        case "1":
            Button temp = (Button) findViewById(btn1);
            if(isOwner) {
                temp.setText("O");
            } else {
                temp.setText("X");
            }
            temp.setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case "You Lose":
            TextView textBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
            textBox.setText("You Lose!");
    }
}
```

And the message I get is:

> java Looper.prepare() wasn't called on this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `activity.handleMessage(messageStr);` you need to send it as a message to the handler, so handleMessage will execute in the loop.

```
 Bundle data = new Bundle();
 data.putString("MESSAGE_KEY", messageStr);
 Message msg = new Message();
 msg.setData(data);
 activity.sendMessage(msg);
```

So you will receive in handleMessage of the Handler the Message, to extract the String you do `message.getData().getString("MESSAGE_KEY");`

Comment: It is now working good, but I cannot figure out how to call methods from the handler that do something with the UI?

Comment: @VasconcelosMarcos

Comment: That depends where you create the Handler, if it is a child class of Activity the outer class is still acessible and you can touch the Views in handleMessage implementation

Answer (score 0):

Create UI thread inside handler and try to perform the UI operation.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // This is where you do your work in the UI thread.
        // Your worker tells you in the message what to do.
    }
};
```

Comment: Updated the answer. try it now.